# Is there an autoreload in cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

Is there a possibility to make an autoreload with cherrypy.

Say reload every 10 sec the page?

It should at least work on firefox and google chrome browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use HTML. It has nothing to do with CherryPy.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```